# How to update / generate database table model?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` and I'm having some problems with the following scenario:

I created an extension class for `IdentityUser` provided by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, the extension class add some extra field to the default database `AspNetUsers`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string LockoutMessage { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

I was able to update the table structure executing the following commands:

```
add-migration <migration name> -context <app context>
update-database
```

*Problem*

Suppose now I used the software `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` for create another table called `UserDetails` which have as `FK` the id of the `AspNetUsers` table.

I want generate the class inside the `Models` folder with all the properties from my application, so I don't need to write manually the property of the table of the new table, how can I do that?

I tried: `update-database` but not seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to bring in stuff from a database is with `Scaffold-DbContext`. However, that's an all or nothing affair. It's going to create entity classes for every table in the database (regardless of whether they already exist) *and* a `DbContext` to boot.

Either you're using code first and you create your entities and generate migrations that you run against the database OR you make changes to the database and then use the `Scaffold-DbContext` command to generate the context and all the associated entities. You cannot mix and match.

Long and short, you need to pick a strategy and stick with it. If you're more comfortable with the database then do everything there and scaffold the code from that. Otherwise, if you want to use code first, then make a commitment to that and never manually touch your database.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: @Charanoglu Personally I would recommend the code-first approach.  Let EF do the bulk of the work by generating migrations (tables, indexes, constraints etc.) that keeps your models and database in sync.  It comes with a learning curve particularly with more complex models but it's worth it.

Comment: @Brad I understood.. the main problem is that now I need to learn EF, in the past I worked with graphical software like MySQL WorkBench, so now seems really difficult do this.